# What electronics are inside the LEGO Powered Up hub?

Tags: electronics, powered-up

I'm curious what the internals of the new Powered Up hub look like? What components are inside?

[image: Powered Up hub]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The bulk of the space inside the Powered Up hub is consumed by the housing for the 6 AAA batteries. A small portion of the top of the hub contains the main printed circuit board. Here's how it looks removed from the hub:

[image: hub front]

And here's another shot showing the back:

[image: hub back]

The main chip is very similar to the one used in Boost. It uses an [STM32F030](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f0-series.html?querycriteria=productId=SS1574) from ST Microelectronics. This includes a 32 bit ARM Cortex-M0 clocked at 48Mhz.

For Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) communication, the Powered Up hub uses a [CC2640 from Texas Instruments](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2640).

The largest chip on the underside of the board is an [LB1836](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LB1836M-D.PDF). I haven't done any testing on the traces, but that part is a dual-channel stepper motor driver and is placed near the output ports, so it is almost certainly used to drive the output current to servo motors. The front side includes a pair of [74HC2G125DP](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT2G125.pdf) chips near the output ports. These are likely used select which CPU pin the output pin is connected to.